# JavaScript syntax error only for Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

For some reason, the following JS declaration causes a syntax error in **Visual Studio** and also fails to execute in Windows Phone browsers, but it's perfectly fine for other IDEs such as NetBeans.

The function comes from the [Windy API Leaflet plugin](https://api4.windy.com/examples/hello-world/) *Hello World* example, and the syntax error is located in the line with the comment:

```
function initWindyMap(lat, lon, key, particlesAnim) {
    const options = {
        key: key,
        lat: lat,
        lon: lon,
        verbose: false,
        zoom: 6
    };
    windyInit(options, windyAPI => { 
        const {overlays, store, map} = windyAPI; /* syntax error on this line */
        store.set('lang', 'es');
        store.set('englishLabels', true);
        store.set('particlesAnim', particlesAnim);
        overlays.wind.setMetric('km/h');
        map.options.minZoom = 6;
        map.options.maxZoom = 6;
        map.dragging.disable();
        map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
        map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
        L.marker(map.getCenter()).addTo(map);
    });
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the Visual Studio IDE for more details.

[image]

The question is: **Is there a more orthodox way to declare this function and avoid this error?** Surely this is a valid syntax in a new JS tweak released minutes ago for the Chrome [webview 75](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en), but I need to use classic, standard JS syntax in this case... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is: **Is there a more orthodox way to declare this function and avoid this error?**

It's an arrow function. They've been standard JavaScript syntax since 2015. They're supported in all vaguely-modern browsers (so not IE11).

You can use a traditional function instead:

```
windyInit(options, function(windyAPI) {
    // ...
});
```

Since yours function doesn't use `this`, there's nothing else you need to do other than just changing the syntax from arrow to traditional. (One of the differences between arrow functions and traditional functions is that arrow functions *close over* `this`, rather than having `this` set by how they're called. More about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).)